# How to use aws polly api to tts a webpage and save in aws s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I am trying to make AWS Polly save a mp3 audio transcription of the contents of an URL. I have tried a couple of pre-baked scripts but none of them seems to work.

This is the blueprint that I am aiming for:
(1) lambda function
- call polly api StartSpeechSynthesisTask
- use as text, the contents of a URL
- save audio file in s3

this is what I have tried in Lambda

```
var request = require("request");

request({uri: "https://www.canalmeio.com.br/ultima-edicao/"}, /*this is the URL where I pick up the text */
    function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
});

var params = {
  OutputFormat: mp3, 
  OutputS3BucketName: 'BUCKETNAMEXXXX'', 
  Text: console.log, 
  VoiceId: Cristiano, 
  Engine: standard,
  LanguageCode: pt-BR,
  OutputS3KeyPrefix: 'meio',
  SampleRate: '22050',
  TextType: text
};
polly.startSpeechSynthesisTask(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I expect the output to be a MP3 file saved in my s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow,

it seems that you have some syntax errors (especially inside the `params`) + you need to wrap the `polly. startSpeechSynthesisTask` within the callback of the request because you depend on the response of the request.

I assume, based on your initally post, that you are working in an AWS Lambda. So try the following

```
var request = require('request');

exports.handler = () => {
    request({ uri: 'https://www.canalmeio.com.br/ultima-edicao/' }, function (error, response, body) {
        var params = {
            OutputFormat: 'mp3',
            OutputS3BucketName: 'BUCKETNAMEXXXX',
            Text: body,
            VoiceId: 'Cristiano',
            Engine: 'standard',
            LanguageCode: 'pt-BR',
            OutputS3KeyPrefix: 'meio',
            SampleRate: '22050',
            TextType: 'text'
        };
        polly.startSpeechSynthesisTask(params, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
            return 'Success';
        });
    });
};
```

**Disclaimer: It's not tested!**